# How does a typical bond ETF provide tax information to the investor in Canada?

Tags: taxes, canada, etf, bonds

Before deciding whether to use registered or unregistered (taxable in Canada) account, I'd like to understand the complexity of tax reporting as a result of holding bond ETF, for example BMO ZFL (long term treasury bonds). Would I need to only report buy/sell for capital gain on my tax return, or would the bank, e.g. BMO - send me dividend statements every year as T5, same way they do with interest on HISA, or would it just be up to me to figure it out on my own without any statements from the bank? I am planning to "buy and hold" for the long term with annual re-balancing with the rest of portfolio if needed.